# Unable to select the select date from calendar with talkback on

Tags: ios, reactjs, datepicker, accessibility

I am seeing an issue in iOS device. I have a react web app which has date picker.

I am unable to select the select date from calendar with talkback on.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're on iOS?  So you're using **VoiceOver**, not **Talkback**, right?  Talkback is for Android.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.